# Question regarding a list of speech titles

Tags: lists

Pretty stumped on how this sentence should look. It just seems like too much punctuation. This is regarding topics for talks at a conference. Thanks!

Topics will include: “Tools of the Trade”, “Making Your Own Tools”, “Industrial Clay: Content and Use”, “How We Finish a Surface”, and “Using Industrial Clay to Cast Molds”.

Comment: Assuming you are in the US by the use of double quotation marks, style dictates that commas and periods go inside closing quotes. Otherwise, your sentence is fine as is: **Topics will include: “Tools of the Trade,” “Making Your Own Tools,” “Industrial Clay: Content and Use,” “How We Finish a Surface,” and “Using Industrial Clay to Cast Molds.”**

The [Chicago Manual of Style](https://www.montgomerycollege.edu/offices/advancement-and-community-engagement/communications/creative-services/editorial-style-guide/quotes-italics-nothing.html) does recommend the use of quotation marks, not italics.

Comment: There is no single right answer, as such questions are largely a matter of style. Adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, adopt a [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579) suitable to your audience and tastes and be consistent in its application.

Comment: What's bothering you?  The commas?  The quotation marks?  The capitalization?

Answer (score 1):

You could convert it into a bulleted list.
*Topics will include:*

- *Tools of the Trade*
- *Making Your Own Tools*
- *Industrial Clay: Content and Use*
- *How We Finish a Surface*
- *Using Industrial Clay to Cast Molds*

This might make subsequently enlarging on each topic a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

Concur with Peter. Not only does the list presentation lead to more extensibility, it seems easier to scan than the original.

If you want to keep as a sentence, how about dropping the quotes:

Topics will include: Tools of the Trade, Making Your Own Tools, Industrial Clay: Content and Use, How We Finish a Surface, and Using Industrial Clay to Cast Molds.